# Using DOMCategory to parse namespace xml's?

Tags: dom, groovy

My input.xml

```
<z1:BookNames name="Groovy" dataType="INTEGER" xmlns:z0="messages" xmlns:z2="base" xmlns:z3="number" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z1="bookcat">
    <z3:BookCost>
        <z3:IntegerValue>1106</z3:IntegerValue>
    </z3:BookCost>
</z1:BookNames>
```

My Code-

```
document = parse(new FileReader('input.xml'))

rootElement = document.documentElement

println rootElement

use(groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory)
{
    println rootElement.'@dataType'
    cf =  rootElement.'z3:BookCost'
}
```

I'm trying to fetch book cost but unsuccessful so far. Can you throw ideas here. I can't declare prefix z3 as 'z3:BookCost' z3 can be anything in input xml. But namespace value can be hard-coded in code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using XmlSlurper:

```
new File( 'input.xml' ).withReader { x ->
  new XmlSlurper().parse( x ).with { root ->
    println root.@dataType
    println root.BookCost.IntegerValue
  }
}
```

DOMCategory [isn't namespace aware](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2147) (afaik)